# Finding the closest matching pair in an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to identify the closest matching pair in an array with an algorithm in n time.

I created a solution at the below repl but I'm not sure what it's Big O is. I would guess maybe (Onlogn) or O(logn). I'd like to get it to O(n) time if possible.

```js
let closestMatchingPair = function(array) {
  if(!array || array.length < 2) {
  return 'invalid data get bent';
 }
 let pairFound = false;
 let position1 = 0;
 let position2 = 0;
 let distance = array.length;

 object = {};
 //build object 
 for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if(!object[array[i]]) {
   object[array[i]] = [i];
  } else {
   object[array[i]].push(i);
  }
 }
  //loop over object properties
 for(let i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
  if(object[array[i]].length >= 2) {
   var closest = object[array[i]].filter(a => a > i).shift();
   if(distance > (closest - i)) {
    position1 = i;
    position2 = closest;
    distance = closest - i;
    pairFound = true;
   }
  }
 }

 return {
  pairFound: pairFound,
  position1: position1,
  position2: position2,
  distance: distance
 }
}

//example [1] = 'invalid data get bent'
//example [1,2] = { pairFound: false, position1: 0, position2: 0, distance: 2 }
//example [1,2,1] = { pairFound: true, position1: 0, position2: 2, distance: 2 }
//example [1,2,1,3,2,2] = { pairFound: true, position1: 4, position2: 5, distance: 1 }
let array = [1,2,1,3,2,2];

console.log(closestMatchingPair(array));
```

https://repl.it/@zack_fanning/PushyGoodnaturedOutput

Working as expected, would like to improve to avoid using filter on line 22 if possible

`var closest = object[array[i]].filter(a => a > i).shift();`

Comment: You think the runtime might be O(log n) and you would like to make it O(n)?!

Comment: Your current code is actually worst-case quadratic time; but yes, you can do this in linear time.

Comment: Loop through the array and update a `value=>position` index. For each element, compare it with the index and update the current min value accordingly. That's O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a lot of work that isn't necessary. It's often a good idea to build an object beforehand as you have, but in this case it's not a win. You only need to iterate over the array once, and there are just a few facts you need to track between iterations:

- `prevPositions` – An object to track the most recent index of each item seen so far.
- `distance` – The smallest distance between any pair so far.
- `position1`, `position2` – The indexes of the pair with the smallest distance so far.

(Technically `distance` can always be calculated by subtracting `position1` from `position2` but we'll save a little work by storing it separately.)

In each iteration you need to:

1. Check if you've seen the current item before.

   - If yes, check if the distance between the current item and its previous occurrence is less than the smallest distance so far.

     - If yes, store the new smallest distance in `distance` and the indexes of the current and previous occurrences in `position1` and `position2`.
2. Store the current item's index in `prevPositions`.

After you've iterated over every item once, `position1`, `position2`, and `distance` will contain the indexes of the closest pair and the distance between them.

This is *O*(*n*). You can see what it looks like in JavaScript in the below snippet.

```js
function closestMatchingPair(array) {
  if (array.length < 2) {
    throw new Error('Input must have at least two items');
  }
  
  // An object to track the most recent positions of the items we've seen so far
  const prevPositions = {};

  // Variables to track the smallest distance so far and corresponding indexes
  let distance, position1, position2;

  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const currentItem = array[index];

    if (currentItem in prevPositions) {
      // We've seen this item before; check if the distance from the previous 
      // instance is less than the smallest distance we've seen so far
      const currentDistance = index - prevPositions[currentItem];

      if (!distance || currentDistance < distance) {
        // New smallest distance; update our variables
        distance = currentDistance;
        position1 = prevPositions[currentItem];
        position2 = index;
        
        if (currentDistance === 1) {
          // Can't do any better than 1; no reason to continue
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    prevPositions[currentItem] = index; // Save item's index
  }

  return { pairFound: !!distance, position1, position2, distance };
}

test([1]);
test([1,2]);
test([1,2,1]);
test([1,2,1,3,2,2]);

function test(input) {
  console.log('input:', input);
  try {
    console.log('output:', closestMatchingPair(input));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

**Note:** This code uses a plain object for `prevPositions`. That works fine as long as your input array contains only numbers, or only strings. However, if your input was e.g. `[1, '1']` the two values would be considered equal because numeric keys are coerced to strings when used as object property names. (Technically it's a bit more complicated than that, but you get the idea.) If you wanted this to work with a mixed array you would need to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This code much better understandable. You can skip line no. 22 from your code. Actually, it is your code with some changes. And the complexity of this code is definitely O(n).

```
  let closestMatchingPair = function(array) {
  if(!array || array.length < 2) {
        return 'invalid data get bent';
    }
    let pairFound = false;
    let position1 = 0;
    let position2 = 0;
    let distance = array.length;

    object = {};
    //build object 
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(!object[array[i]]) {
            object[array[i]] = [i];
        } else {
            object[array[i]].push(i);
        }
    }
  //loop over object properties
    for(x in object) {
    var item = object[x];
    for(let i=1; i<item.length; i++){
      if(item[i]-item[i-1] < distance){
        pairFound = true;
        position1 = item[i-1],
        position2 = item[i],
        distance = item[i]-item[i-1];
      } 
    }
  }

    return {
        pairFound: pairFound,
        position1: position1,
        position2: position2,
        distance: distance
    }
}

//example [1] = 'invalid data get bent'
//example [1,2] = { pairFound: false, position1: 0, position2: 0, distance: 2 }
//example [1,2,1] = { pairFound: true, position1: 0, position2: 2, distance: 2 }
//example [1,2,1,3,2,2] = { pairFound: true, position1: 4, position2: 5, distance: 1 }
let array = [1,2,1,3,2,2];

closestMatchingPair(array);
```

You can check there also [link](https://repl.it/repls/DutifulRichOctal)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
```

looks wasteful. For your input array `let array = [1,2,1,3,2,2]`, you iterate through the whole thing. Checking `object[1]`, `object[2]`, `object[1]` *again*, and so on.

Iterate through the keys of `object` instead.